# How can i disable log4j servlet initialization?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

The scenario is the following:
I have an existing web app, which initializes log4j through a servlet:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>log4j-init</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.app.Log4jInitServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>log4j-init-file</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

No i want to override this initialization through an external file passed in log4j.configuration JVM ardument: -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/usr/local/log4j.xml

When i start the application server I can see that the external file is being picked up first but then the internal file through the initialization servlet will override the changes.

My question is how can i disable the servlet initialization through some king of JVM param configuration(preferable), without having to modify the application web.xml and/or initialization servlet?
Or is there a way to specify the order in which the initialization should be done ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to source of Log4jInitServlet. The order would already be specified in the init servlet

Comment: No i don't have access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log4j init servlet is not part of core log4j. I'll assume that you are using the init servlet suggested in tutorial present here https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html
In such a case whatever file you specify in the servlet init file parameter is going to be used for init.

I don't think you can accomplish this without modifying either the web.xml or the init servlet